# Iterate a select query for a set of varchar2 in oracle

Tags: oracle, loops

I have a below select query

```
    select * from BUSINESS_T
where  store_code = '075'
and item_no in
(
         select item_no from BUSINESS_T a
         where store_code = '075'
         and exists
         (
                  select * from BUSINESS_T
                  where store_code = a.store_code 
                  and item_no = a.item_no
                  and
                  (
                            VALID_FROM_DTIME between a.VALID_FROM_DTIME and a.VALID_TO_DTIME
                            or VALID_TO_DTIME between a.VALID_FROM_DTIME and a.VALID_TO_DTIME
                            or (VALID_FROM_DTIME > a.VALID_FROM_DTIME and a.VALID_TO_DTIME is null)
                            or (VALID_FROM_DTIME < a.VALID_FROM_DTIME and VALID_TO_DTIME is null)
                  )
                  and del_dtime is null
                  and not
                  (
                            a.rowid = rowid
                  )
         )
)
order by item_no, VALID_FROM_DTIME
```

Need to run it for a array of store numbers {'071','072','073','074','075','076'}
This array should defined inside the query itself.

Nearly 400+ fixed store numbers are there. The above query has to be run for each store, at a time for one store , To find the overlapping in that particular store

Comment: Where are your store numbers?

Comment: Pass from where outside, and how? Please edit your question to include the code that executes this SQL and to show how the caller has those numbers, e.g. in a native array. (You probably want to pass in a collection of values, but the application type/language will determine if that is possible and how it should be done.) Based on your comment on GMB's answer this query is a small part of what you are trying to do, so please also explain that clearly too, and where/when the multiple values are used.

Comment: "query has to be run for each store" - as one combined result set? If so - why can't you use `in` (or, preferably, still pass a collection). Or does your application need to run it one-by-one for each of the site IDs it has?

Comment: If i run by passing the collection of store numbers, there is a chance items are common in many stores that will cause a problem. query itself has to read the store number from array and run the select query for that store.This query has to be run by the support people using sql developer, Not by any code or procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i run by passing the collection of store numbers, there is a chance items are common in many stores that will cause a problem.

You can still use `in` if you modify the first subquery to get return the store/item pairs, which handles the common items:

```
select * from BUSINESS_T
where (store_code, item_no) in
(
         select store_code, item_no from BUSINESS_T a
         where store_code in ('071','072','073','074','075','076')
...
```

Or with a collection:

```
select * from BUSINESS_T
where (store_code, item_no) in
(
         select store_code, item_no from BUSINESS_T a
         where store_code member of sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('071','072','073','074','075','076')
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=195c0f7ce371b2771a91fabd76ef0e02) with very simple demo of the idea.

Comment: In above your answer store_code in ('071','072','073','074','075','076'), i need to get the store_codes from the same table. as select distinct(store_code) from BUSINESS_T, but query taking too time give response.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You just want to know which of the codes in that list exist at all in the table? You should probably ask a new question showing your query, data volumes, expected output etc. But you're probably looking for the `exists()` condition.

Comment: as in above working query i hard coded the store_code, i need to get that from the same table by querying select distinct(store_code) from BUSINESS_T, after enhancing this response time is increased.

Comment: select * from BUSINESS_T
where (store_code, item_no) in
(
         select store_code, item_no from BUSINESS_T a
         where store_code in (select distinct(store_code) from BUSINESS_T)

Comment: @Gangs165700 - three levels of query against the same table for this doesn't really make sense, but I think you can simplify to a main query with an exists clause to check the date ranges. You originally said the IDs were passed in from outside. *This* question has been answered. Please as a new question explaining the new situation and issues you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Use `in`:

```
select *
from business_t
where 
    class_unit_code in ('071', '072', '073', '074', '075', '076')
    and b_type = 'CASH_AND_CARRY' 
    and delete_date is null
```

For this specific sequence of string values, we might try to shorten the predicate using a regex (although this is probably less efficient):

```
regexp_like(class_unit_code, '^07[1-6]$')
```

Or if the string *always* contains numeric values, we can convert and use a range comparison (which also is not as efficient as the first option - in that case, the column should have been created with a numeric datatype to start with):

```
to_number(class_unit_code) between 71 and 76
```

Comment: Here at a time i have to pass only one store_number. That is stopping me to use  IN operator.Its a very big inner query,3 select 's are there 1 inside the other. This select main usage is to find the overlapping items in that particular store.

Comment: I updated the question with the complete overlapping query now